# Permission denied (publickey) on capifony deployment from windows with remote host gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, capifony

I am trying to setup a deployment from my local windows computer through gitlab to my server using capifony.

Usually I would connect by ssh to my server and run the command from the server
Now I want to do it from my local computer.

I am already pushing code from my local computer to gitlab with git, i.e. my public key is registered on gitlab.

Here however, it's not working with capifony.
What could be the issue ?

The error :

```
D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev>cap development deploy
 ** transaction: start
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: my_server_ip (ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line)
connection failed for: my_server_ip (ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line)
```

**EDIT :**

If I follow the instructions given in several post and I put in my deploy.rb the following options

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

or

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
```

Then I am asked for a root password and I still get an error (despite the fact I can log in via ssh with putty directly and that running the deployment from my server with another user works without me entering the root password):

```
D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev>cap preprod deploy
 ** transaction: start
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
root@my_server_ip's password:
 ** [my_server_ip  :: err] Error reading response length from authentication socket.
 ** [my_server_ip  :: err] Permission denied (publickey).
 ** [my_server_ip  :: err] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 **
 ** Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 ** and the repository exists.
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/foodmeup.net/preprod/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/foodmeup.net/preprod/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --ha
rd f52737bb09edbd968319400e2d535f467c42b04c && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b preprod git@gitlab.com:svassaux/foodmeup.git /home/foodmeup.net/preprod/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/foodme
up.net/preprod/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy f52737bb09edbd968319400e2d535f467c42b04c; fi'" on my_server_ip
```

Comment: Are you using UNIX/Linux paths on a windows machine?

Comment: well, I tried with ssh_options[:keys] = 'C:\Users\Sébastien\.ssh\id_rsa.pub' but it does not work either...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/286), one possible reason is:

> My problem was that I needed to enclose my ssh key file location in quotes in my `config/deploy.rb` file, like this:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
```

> instead of:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
```

Also:

> I got this error even when I dont set `ssh_options[:keys]` in my `deploy.rb`.

Or:

> This problem may be caused by ssh private key with passphrase and no ssh public key.

(also mentioned in [issues/101](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/101#issuecomment-53506615))

> Try remove `ssh_options[:keys]` and invoke the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

That leads to:

> I launched [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and found ruby process trying to load file `~.ssh\key.pub.pub` which gave me an idea that path to the private (not public) key should be in `ssh_config['keys']`.
>
> So this should work:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

Read also [ArgumentError: Could not parse PKey: no start line](http://coding-journal.com/argumenterror-could-not-parse-pkey-no-start-line/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this effortof summing all up. I already tried it all and this does not yet solve my issue. I've made an edit. maybe you understand what's happening?

Comment: @Sébastien I see you have two `ssh_options[:keys]`: keep only one, the one with the private key. As I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: sure, I wrote too fast, I tried both but I get the same error : it asks for a root password and then it fails. I'm not asked for a root password when I deploy from the server itself nor when I connect through to my server from putty... I don't understand what's missing here

Comment: @Sébastien is there a difference in the account used, between your test from putty, which works, and your local session, which would explain that the ssh keys are not found where expected?

Comment: there is not explanation because I can also use the windows command line to push to git without having to define a location for my keys

Answer (score 0):

Set `ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa')` , do not set the `ssh_options[:keys] = %w('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')`